# iOS - layout constraints guide for dynamic height of table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm new to iOS development and am stucked with the problem to finish my layout with dynamic content..

Generally layout I'm trying to implement is quite popular, as an example:

[image]

and here is screenshot of **my storyboard**:

[image]

and **table cell hierarchy**:

[image]

The main question what are the main rules of building **dynamic height** table cell with **dynamic height** uiview inside it? The content could be long, so do I need to add constraints to bottom of the view?

Is it possible in Storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with storyboard (I might be wrong...): `UITableView` can have cells with a fixed size - using `UITableView` `rowHeight` property - or its delegate can provide a different size for any indexPath.

Constraints provided in Storyboard (or programmatically) only help layout the cell's subviews ONCE the cell's frame has been set.

So I think you should look to `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, and a way to compute programmatically your cells' height dynamically.

Comment: yeah.. feels like a bit too complex for beginner like me :)

Comment: Not necessarily : lots of `UIControls `come with a `sizeThatFits` methods, which - if called with  `CGSizeZero` gives you the fitting size of the control. So you would only have - for each cell - to sum the fitting height of the controls you stack vertically.